# How to create 2 separate m2 repositories in Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, java-8, build

We have an existing project with old version of jars.
And we created a new branch and upgrading the jars to latest version available.

Also, We have separate servers to test these. But when i try to deploy, builds are failing since they are sharing same .m2 repositories.

Is there a way to have two separate m2 folders for each server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when i try to deploy, builds are failing since they are sharing
>   same .m2 repositories.

In each `settings.xml` of define the path for local repo as below:

```
<localRepository>R:/some_m2_folder/snapshotviews/repo</localRepository>
```

and

```
<localRepository>C:/some_m2_folder/snapshotviews/repo</localRepository>
```